# Splitting cells in table while preserving other information

Tags: r

I've got a table that I would like to process in **R**. Two of the cells stores coordinates (start and end) that are comma-separated. I would like to split these coordinates such that they are on their own lines but maintain the information from the other cells in the row.

Example table:

```
header1  header2  start        end
data1    data2    1,100,200    99,199,299
```

Desired output:

```
data1    data2    1     99
data1    data2    100   199
data1    data2    200   299
```

How does one go about doing this in **R**?

Comment: Can you provide the actual structure of your "table" object using `dput(table)` (where "table" is the name of the object) as an edit to your question?

Comment: See `concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package. Use `direction ="long"`.

Comment: Are the number of split values in each row for "start" and "end" always the same (in this case, there are three values)?

Comment: @AnandaMahto It is not always three values. It varies from 1 to 737.

Comment: @reedms, but the length of items in each row of "start" and "end" are the same, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto not necessarily, if I am interpreting your question correctly. It's not uncommon for something to start at 10 and end at something like 300.

Comment: @reedms, no. What I mean is that for every start value (eg 1, above), there will be an end value (eg 99, above). That is to say, if the second row had five comma separated values in "start", would there also be five comma separated values in "end"?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, how big are your actual data?

Comment: The file was 54,000+ lines. After processing it becomes over 250,000 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your table is called `df`. The `data.table` package makes this kind of reshaping trivial...

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table( df )
dt[ , list(start = strsplit(start , ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]], 
           end   = strsplit(end , ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]] 
          ), by = c("header1","header2") ]

#   header1 header2 start end
#1:   data1   data2     1  99
#2:   data1   data2   100 199
#3:   data1   data2   200 299
```

Comment: When I tried this with my real data set, it only worked on the first 350 sets of coordinates. It also required me to use strsplit(as.character(start), ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]],

Comment: So post the 350/351st rows of your data... Impossible to say without it.

Comment: chrUn_random + 551804, 551833,\n
chrUn_random + 552839, 552900,\n

Comment: When I am using the by = c("header1", "header2) is it possible it stops at 350 because that is the number of unique combinations of each of those characteristics in my data file?

Comment: @reedms, if that's the case, then add a new id variable.

Comment: @AnandaMahto This seems to have worked! I'll need to verify a few records manually, though!

Answer (score 1):

I really like the elegance of Simon's `data.table` approach. Here's an old-school R version:

```
# your original data
dat <- data.frame(header1="data1", header2="data2", 
                  start="1,100,200", end="99,199,299")
dat
##   header1 header2     start        end
## 1   data1   data2 1,100,200 99,199,299     

dat <- data.frame(dat[,c(1,2)],
             start=do.call('cbind', strsplit(as.character(dat$start), ',')),
             end=do.call('cbind', strsplit(as.character(dat$end), ',')))
dat
##   header1 header2 start end
## 1   data1   data2     1  99
## 2   data1   data2   100 199
## 3   data1   data2   200 299
```

Comment: When I'm using this method I get an error: "number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)".

Comment: @reedms, you have been asked to provide a reproducible example, but haven't done so yet. If you do so, I'm sure the quality of the answers you get would improve and help you solve your problem more directly and efficiently.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, is it still considered elegant if more involved code [is hidden behind a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23322297/1270695)? Also, [an ancient blog-post of mine](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/)....

Answer (score 0):

I would actually write a function that looks like this:

```
NewSplit <- function(indf, splitCols, sep = ",") {
  Keys <- setdiff(names(indf), splitCols)
  if (any(!vapply(indf[splitCols], is.character, logical(1L)))) {
    indf[splitCols] <- lapply(indf[splitCols], as.character)
  }
  X <- setNames(lapply(indf[splitCols], function(x) {
    strsplit(x, split = sep, fixed = TRUE)
  }), splitCols)
  Rep <- vapply(X[[1]], length, integer(1L))
  cbind(indf[rep(rownames(indf), Rep), Keys], 
        lapply(X, unlist), 
        row.names = NULL,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

and that can be used like this:

```
NewSplit(dat, c("start", "end"), ",")
#    header1 header2 id start end
# 1        A       F  1     1  99
# 2        A       F  1   100 199
# 3        A       F  1   200 299
# 4        B       G  1    11  33
# 5        B       G  1   222 444
# 6        C       H  1    10  72
# 7        D       I  1     7  10
# 8        D       I  1     8   9
# 9        D       I  1     9   8
# 10       D       I  1    10   7
# 11       D       I  1    11   6
# 12       E       J  1     1   3
```

where "dat" is defined as:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  header1 = LETTERS[1:5], header2 = LETTERS[6:10], 
  start = c("1,100,200", "11,222", "10", "7,8,9,10,11", "1"),
  end = c("99,199,299", "33,444", "72", "10,9,8,7,6", "3"))

dat$id <- with(dat, 
                ave(rep(1, nrow(dat)), 
                    header1, header2, 
                    FUN = seq_along))
```

---

This is actually a pretty fast function as it is, because the base functions being used are pretty fast. Here's a comparison with the "data.table" answer on 50K rows.

#### Expand the original dataset to 50K rows

```
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, dat, FALSE))
dat2$id <- with(dat2, 
                ave(rep(1, nrow(dat2)), 
                    header1, header2, 
                    FUN = seq_along))
dim(dat2)
# [1] 50000     5
dt <- as.data.table(dat2)
```

#### Create a couple of functions to test (for convenience)

```
fun1 <- function(dt = dt) {
  dt[, list(
    start = strsplit(as.character(start) , ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]], 
    end   = strsplit(as.character(end) , ",", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]), 
    by = list(header1, header2, id)]
}

fun2 <- function(df = dat2) {
  NewSplit(df, c("start", "end"), ",")
}
```

#### Check that they are equal

```
all.equal(as.data.frame(fun1(dt)), fun2(dat2))
# [1] TRUE
```

#### Compare times

```
system.time(fun1(dt))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.953   0.009   1.999 

system.time(fun2(dat2))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.286   0.001   0.288
```